# Boolean check if a string matches a regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

In ruby, I have seen a lot of code doing things like:

```
def test(s)
  s =~ /Macintosh/
end
```

to test whether or not a string matches a regex. However, this returns a fixnum or nil, depending on if it finds a match. Is there a way to do the same operation, but have it return a boolean as to whether or not it matched?

The two possible solutions that I thought of were `!(s =~ /Macintosh/).nil?` and `!(s !~ /Macintosh/)`, but neither of those seem very readable. Is there something like:

```
def test(s)
  s.matches?(/Macintosh/)
end
```

Comment: What about `!!(string =~ /some regex/)`?

Comment: @rathrio that would check and then check for nil, I'm asking if there's a boolean method that would return true or false.

Comment: Just out of interest: Is there a specific reason why you want a Boolean? In most use cases returning nil or a non-nil value would work just fine, right?

Comment: @rathrio The problem is, if the needle is at position 0 in the haystack, =~ returns 0. And while ruby evaluates 0 as true, mysql doesn't. It's a rails thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this:

```
def test(s)
    /Macintosh/ === s
end
```

Comment: The question is whether or not there exists a method that does a boolean check, without needing to check nil at the end. !! is the same as .nil?.

Comment: @kdeisz: where is the gift basket?

Comment: I am having a rubocop error for this...       Avoid the use of the case equality operator(===).   How can i use match method instead === ?

Comment: BTW, it's good style to add a `?` to a boolean method, as in `test?(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary syntax might help or fit a different style preference:

```
x = '10.0.0'
x =~ /\d*\.\d*\.\d*/ ? true : false  # => true

# Unlike c-style languages, 0 is true in ruby:
x =~ /\d*\.\d*\.\d*/                 # => 0
0 ? true : false                     # => true
```

The order of the case compare operator `===` is important [1], e.g.:

```
/\d*\.\d*\.\d*/ === x
#=> true
x === /\d*\.\d*\.\d*/
#=> false
```

[1]  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

Answer (score 0):

Since [Ruby 2.4.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/), you can use [Regexp#match](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Regexp#match%3F-instance_method) which returns a boolean result;

```
/Macintosh/.match?(s)
```